# When should I use @Override for toString method

Tags: java, eclipse, tostring

I'm studying java and have a question about toString method.
In both case:

```
//**Case1: **
@Override
public String toString(){
   return "Hello world";
}

//**Case2:** 
public String toString(){
   return "Hello world";
}
```

So my question is when should we need to include the *@Override*. Because basically the case2 is Override it already. Why we need to *@Override* it again.

Understanding how toString work

Comment: If _Case1_ and _Case2_ are methods of the same class, then they are duplicate methods, which is not allowed in Java. `@Override` need to be included always for the `public String toString()` method, since `java.lang.Object` contains this method and all classes inherit from `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: Essentially, if you think you're overriding a method of a parent class, use `@Override`, this provides a compile time check to ensure that you're actually doing what you think you're doing (and don't end up wondering why your code doesn't work as expected)

Comment: Thank you howlger and MadProgrammer for make clear how @Override work.

Answer (score 8):

***Always*** use `@Override` on `toString()`, because it is always overriding `Object.toString()`.  The annotation is simply there to tell the compiler that you *intend* to override a function in a superclass.  That way, for example, if you misspell the name of the function and it no longer matches the function name in the superclass, the compile will fail.

Comment: Thank you. I will note that. But without the annotation. The compiler will automatic understand it and override it right? I just want to make sure

Comment: @TruongNguyen Correct, overriding happens regardless of annotation. The annotation does not cause overriding; the annotation is just a witness. Without annotation you’ll not know if you have a typo that inadvertently defines a new method rather than override.

Comment: @TruongNguyen And to add what @BasilBourque has said, this is the ***entire*** purpose of the `@Override` annotation.  ***Always*** use it when you are intending to override the member of a superclass.